# How disable to select minutes in v-time-picker widget?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, time, vuetify.js

In my **Vue.js** application, I use [v-time-picker](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/time-pickers) widget of the **Vuetify** framework. I want to disable to select minutes. If user select hour, automatically inserted 00 in minutes. How to make it correctly? Right now I set `allowed-minutes` props but in that case, user needs to select minutes anyway.

```
<template>
  <v-time-picker
    full-width
    scrollable
    format="24hr"
    :disabled="timePickerDisabled"
    :allowed-minutes="allowedMinutes"
    v-model="selectedTimePickerItems">
  </v-time-picker>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      selectedTimePickerItems: null,
      timePickerDisabled: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    allowedMinutes: m => m % 60 === 0
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a click event on hour @click:hour. The event emits the current value of timepicker. You can utilize that to set the data.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/abzEWPE

```js
 <div id="app">
  <v-app>
       <v-menu
        v-model="menu"
        max-width="290px"
        min-width="290px"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-text-field
            :value="time"
            label="Picker in menu"
            readonly
            v-on="on"
          ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-time-picker
          v-if="menu"
          :value="time"
          @click:hour="closePicker"
        ></v-time-picker>
      </v-menu>
  </v-app>
</div>

var vApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    time: null,
    menu: false
  },
  methods: {
    closePicker: function(v){
      v = v < 10 ? '0'+v : v;
      this.time = v+":00";
      this.menu = false
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `closePicker` method set `00` minute as I want, but in my case, I have only `v-time-picker`. I don't have `v-text-field` as in your example. After hour selection widget makes an animation to minutes block. I want to disable that animation and don't show minutes block. Is it possible for your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to disable all but hours. This approach also works with always-visible VTimePickers.

1. You need to immediately go back to the hour selection after an hour
   has been selected. Use `ref`, `@click:hour`, `$nextTick` and the inner property `selectingHour` for this.
2. Prevent the user to manually switch to the minutes (or seconds) selection with `pointer-events: none;`.

```html
<v-time-picker ref="picker"
               @click:hour="selectingHourIfUseHoursOnly"
               class="custom-time-picker">
  You can select only full hour time points for this field.
</v-time-picker>
```

```js
methods: {
  selectingHourIfUseHoursOnly() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.picker.selectingHour = true;
    });
  },
},
```

```css
.custom-time-picker .v-time-picker-title {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Have a look at my codepen: https://codepen.io/sebu10n/pen/yLoVZyV

Answer (score 0):

Combined solution with `<v-text-field>` element usage:

```
<v-col>
  <v-menu
    ref="menu"
    v-model="timeMenu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :nudge-right="50"
    :return-value.sync="time"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    max-width="290px"
    min-width="290px"
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="time"
        label="Time in hours"
        prepend-icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline"
        readonly
        v-bind="attrs"
        v-on="on"
      />
    </template>
    <v-time-picker
      v-if="timeMenu"
      v-model="time"
      format="24hr"
      light
      no-title
      full-width
      @click:hour="closePicker"
    />
  </v-menu>
</v-col>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    time: null,
    timeMenu: false,
  };
},
created() {
  const now = new Date(Date.now() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
  this.time = this.getTimeStr(now);
},
methods: {
  getFormattedTime: (h) => `${`00${h}`.slice(-2)}:00`,
  getTimeStr(dt) {
    return this.getFormattedTime(dt.getUTCHours());
  },
  closePicker(t) {
    this.time = this.getFormattedTime(t);
    this.$refs.menu.save(this.time);
    this.timeMenu = false;
  },
}
```