# How in v-time-picker to disable to choose the minutes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In my **Vue.js** application, I use [v-time-picker](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/time-pickers) widget of the **Vuetify** framework. Is there any way to disable to choose the minutes? If user select hour, `v-time-picker` widget automatically switches to minutes block. I want to save focus in hour block. As you can see in my case when user select hour I set minutes value programmatically. For that's why I don't need to show minutes block to the user.

```
<template>
<v-time-picker
    ref="timePicker"
    full-width
    format="24hr"
    no-title
    @click:hour="changeTimePickerValue"
    v-model="selectedTimePickerValue">
</v-time-picker>
<template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            selectedTimePickerValue: null
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.$refs.timePicker.onChange = function () {
            // this.$emit(`click:${selectingNames[this.selecting]}`, value)
            if (this.inputHour === this.lazyInputHour &&
                this.inputMinute === this.lazyInputMinute &&
                (!this.useSeconds || this.inputSecond === this.lazyInputSecond)
            ) return
            const time = this.genValue()
            if (time === null) return
            this.lazyInputHour = this.inputHour
            this.lazyInputMinute = this.inputMinute
            this.useSeconds && (this.lazyInputSecond = this.inputSecond)
            this.$emit('change', time)
        }.bind(this.$refs.timePicker)
    },
    methods: {
        changeTimePickerValue: function (v) {
            v = v < 10 ? '0' + v : v
            this.selectedTimePickerValue = v + ':00'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you need fast solution, or something more complex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disable to select minutes in v-time-picker widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607056/how-disable-to-select-minutes-in-v-time-picker-widget)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets do it.

As we can see inside VTimePicker, there is property `selecting` which is enum of [1,2,3] for `hour`, `minutes`, `seconds`.

We have no access to this data directly, and there is no API in component interface for it.
But can such stuff stop glorious explorers, like we are? Of course not.

We can see `onChange` handler, which do all stuff, after timePicker was changed.

```
onChange (value: number) {
      this.$emit(`click:${selectingNames[this.selecting]}`, value)

      const emitChange = this.selecting === (this.useSeconds ? SelectingTimes.Second : SelectingTimes.Minute)

      if (this.selecting === SelectingTimes.Hour) {
        this.selecting = SelectingTimes.Minute
      } else if (this.useSeconds && this.selecting === SelectingTimes.Minute) {
        this.selecting = SelectingTimes.Second
      }

      if (this.inputHour === this.lazyInputHour &&
        this.inputMinute === this.lazyInputMinute &&
        (!this.useSeconds || this.inputSecond === this.lazyInputSecond)
      ) return

      const time = this.genValue()
      if (time === null) return

      this.lazyInputHour = this.inputHour
      this.lazyInputMinute = this.inputMinute
      this.useSeconds && (this.lazyInputSecond = this.inputSecond)

      emitChange && this.$emit('change', time)
    },
```

It is obvious, that in our use-case we need that stuff just to fire `this.$emit('change', time)` at the end, so we can, like really oldfags, do next:

```
    <v-time-picker
          ref="timePicker"
          full-width
          format="24hr"
          v-model="picked"
        >
        </v-time-picker>

       mounted() {

        this.$refs.timePicker.onChange = function () {

          this.$emit(`click:${selectingNames[this.selecting]}`, value)

if (this.inputHour === this.lazyInputHour &&
        this.inputMinute === this.lazyInputMinute &&
        (!this.useSeconds || this.inputSecond === this.lazyInputSecond)
      ) return

          const time = this.genValue();
          if (time === null) return;

          this.lazyInputHour = this.inputHour;
          this.lazyInputMinute = this.inputMinute;
          this.useSeconds && (this.lazyInputSecond = this.inputSecond);

          this.$emit('change', time);
        }.bind(this.$refs.timePicker);
```

We have to do all that wierd `bind` coz Vue proxy `this` to component instance, but that stuff will do the job.

BTW you even do not need to handle `allowedMinutes`, coz user will never get there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Did you test your code? My `ESLint` raise error to this part of your code: `this.$emit('click:${selectingNames[this.selecting]}', value)`. Details: `selectingNames and value are not defined (no-undef)`. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: You can remove that part, it is just to emit `click:hour` event, so if you do not use it, you can remove it.

Comment: I already removed that part as you recommended. In that case, it shows me the next error in the console, unfortunately: `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'onChange' of undefined"`.

Comment: did you made a ref to it inside your template?

Comment: Yes, I did. You can check my post again. I update it with your code.

Comment: It was wrapped to another component previously. And why do you use both v-model and `on` handler?  Do you use `mounted` in the file where v-time-picker is? Very hard to track issues when I write something for code which was changed after it

Comment: I notice interesting behavior. I put your code in my `changeTimePickerValue` function. Instead of `this.$refs.timePicker` I use `this.$refs.timePicker[0]`. You can check it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NogerbekNurzhan/5vwphnrj/11/). First I select the hour, then widget changes the focus to minutes block. Then I switch to hour block and select the hour again. Only in that case widget doesn't change the focus to minutes block. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: Let me know if you have any ideas, please.